# Update single web resource in CRM 2015 managed solution

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015, ie-developer-tools, ie11-developer-tools

I have managed solution deployed on CRM 2015 instance. There is error in one of the JS Web Resources which I need to fix (I need to add few additional lines of code). I thought that update of managed solution would be helpful here. Following was done:

1. I took ZIP of the original solution, found the file in WebResources folder and added my changes to it, saved, and zipped everything again.
2. Imported solution as update of existing managed solution to CRM.
3. Published everything.
4. When I run my code, it is not executed. When I try debugging IE Developer Tools are showing that older version of changed JS file is actually being loaded and run (without my changes). 
   [image]

[image]

Don't know what to do. By reading MSDN manual about how solutions are applied, that should be it. I chose "overwrite" option when I was upgrading managed solution. Can anyone help? What's the best approach of updating single web resource of managed CRM solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new solution with the same publisher name as your managed solution.
2. Add a Javascript web resource with exactly the same name to your solution.
3. Export your solution as a managed solution.
4. Import your new solution in the target system.
5. Remove your new solution.